# how to get yesterday from whenever the QdateEdit pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using a PyQt5 GUI application and I need to get the value of yesterdays from any date in the QdateEdite I have inside the GUI application, for example I want to choose the day I use this code

```
date_n = str(self.dateEdit_2.text())
```

How can I get the ysterday of the day_n whenever the date_n it will be?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to get the date of the day *before* that of the QDateEdit?

Comment: yes that exactly what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the QDate from QDateEdit, then subtract one day from it and then convert it to a string:

```
selected_dt = self.dateEdit_2.date()
last_dt = selected_dt.addDays(-1)
last_dt_str = last_dt.toString(self.dateEdit_2.displayFormat())
print(last_dt_str)
```